# condicionar el numero de hoja a usar segun el valor en una celda en una macro

Tags: excel, vba, condiciones, macros

Tengo un archivo con Hojas según el número de día del mes. O sea, Hoja 1, Hoja 2; Hoja 3; etc. Quiero ejecutar una macro según el día especificado en una celda. Por ejemplo colocar en A1 el valor "5" y de esta manera ejecutar la macro que tengo en la hoja del día anterior, es decir la Hoja 4. Soy muy básica con el tema de macros y las realizo "demostrativamente" en excel. Es decir, le doy grabar y hago los pasos a realizar. Pero como es condicional a un numero que varia, quisiera que por favor me ayuden a la escritura de esa condicional para que corra lo deseado. Mil gracias. Espero puedan ayudarme.

Slds

Comment: Hola. Deberías poner el código que tengas, por poco que sea. Pero sin poner nada, es difícil ayudar. Algo como `Worksheets("Hoja " & Range("A1").value-1).activate`, debería activar la hoja con un número anterior al que hayas puesto en A1

Comment: Gracias Elier! me ayudaste un millón!!! era lo que necesitaba saber como escribir

Answer (score 0):

debes realizar si tu ejecutas la macro, la macro leera la celda A1 y si es 5 lo que tiene que hacer es ir a la hoja 4, si es 8 tiene que ir a la hoja 7, y asi sucesivamente, te dejo una parte del codigo para que te guies.

```
 Sub condicional()

If Sheets("Inicio").Range("a1") = 1 Then
    Sheets("Hoja1").Select
ElseIf Sheets("Inicio").Range("a1") = 2 Then
    Sheets("Hoja1").Select
ElseIf Sheets("Inicio").Range("a1") = 3 Then
    Sheets("Hoja2").Select
ElseIf Sheets("Inicio").Range("a1") = 4 Then
    Sheets("Hoja3").Select
End If

End Sub
```

No dudes en comentarnos tus dudas.